# How to select (All) in a pivot table filter

Tags: excel, vba

I need  `(All)` to be selected in my pivot table

I tried the following

```
Dim pf As PivotField
 Set pf = Worksheets("xxx").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("myFilterField")
   For Each Pi In pf.PivotItems
          Pi.Visible = True
        Next Pi
```

This works very slowly, and not well

Another option does not work at all . It selects only some of the items that were selected previously

```
Worksheets("xxx").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("myFilterField").CurrentPage = "(All)"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could be calling .Visible = True for a couple of reasons so hopefully one of the below covers what you are trying to do:

If you mean you want to set all the Pi to be visible in one step then rather than enumerating through the Pi in pf.PivotItems just:

`pf.ShowAllItems = True`

If, on the other hand, you mean you want clear all filters then:

`pf.ClearAllFilters()`

Or, if you want to just clear manual filters (i.e. not filters applied against an actual row/column filed but rather against a filter field) then:

`pf.ClearManualFilters`

Consult help on PivotField Object Members for the full list

Comment: Thank you. However, it does not do the trick for me for some reason

Comment: @Buras thanks - I realise now you could be referring to a couple of things depending on the reason for wanting to make them visible. PLease see my edited answer, in particular the pf.ClearManualFilters (the '(All)' I think you are referring to is about the drop down on a filter). If that doesn't do the trick then let me know!

Comment: `pf.ShowAllItems = True` crashes my application. No idea why. But `pf.ClearAllFilters` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
Worksheets("xxx").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("myFilterField").ClearAllFilters
```