# Pivot: VBA to check the select all but blank in a pivot table

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, pivot-table

Hi I have a question regarding Pivot tables

With help of the topic below I managed to get a code but it doesn't work, hopefully anybody can see where it goes wrong.
[How to select (All) in a pivot table filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793680/how-to-select-all-in-a-pivot-table-filter)

Preferably, the VBA should SELECT ALL and, if possible, than unselect the BLANK, but I didn't reach that point yet:

```
Sub Showallpivot()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
    pf.ShowAllItems = True
Next pf
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the post a little closer. You duplicated the question instead of following the answer.

Comment: Oh wow, what a stupid mistake, let me dig into that answer agian.. This time a bit closer..

Comment: @OldUgly, sorry to bother again, but :  pf.ShowAllItems = True should be the answer for me right? however, I'm probably making a mistake somewhere? any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "answer" in the post you linked to, using your code, would look something like this ...

```
Sub Showallpivot()
Dim pt As PivotTable

    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    pt.ClearAllFilters

End Sub
```

This will remove any filtering that has been put in place, leaving the PivotTable in its full form.

If this doesn't do what you want, then you need to provide a clearer explanation of what the problem is.

Your comment *"Preferably, the VBA should SELECT ALL and, if possible, than unselect the BLANK, but I didn't reach that point yet"* implies you are looking for other information, beyond showing all of the pivot table. You have not provided enough detail for me to comment further. It should be a separate question.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I focused to much on the 'show all' rather than 'clear all'. The last part of my questions: all filters are cleared now, but after it cleared all filters, there should be 1 filter, which unselects the 'Blanks'.. does that make any sense? code below doesn't work properly..

    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    pt.ClearAllFilters
    pt.PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False

Comment: @bart1701 - Should be a separate question.

Comment: ok thanks! will dig into this more, hopefully I can find this somewhere on the forum, otherwise I will start a new Q. thanks again!

Comment: Selecting all but blank is definitely in the scope of this question.